Vertx difference between onComplete and onSuccess
Whats the difference between using onComplete and onSuccess.
Will onComplete will wait for all futures to complete and then execute
CompositeFuture.join(results)
.onComplete(
    ar -> {
      if (ar.succeeded()) {
        List<JsonObject> queryResponses = new ArrayList<>();
        results.forEach(
            ft -> {
              if (ft.succeeded()) {
                queryResponses.addAll((List<JsonObject>) ft.result());
              }
            });
      } else {
        responsePromise.fail(ar.cause());
      }
    })
.onFailure(responsePromise::fail);

and
CompositeFuture.join(results)
    .onSuccess(
        ar -> {
          List<JsonObject> queryResponses = new ArrayList<>();
          results.forEach(
              ft -> {
              if (ft.success()) {
                queryResponses.addAll((List<JsonObject>) ft.result());
                } else {
                queryResponses.add(Collections.emptyList());
                }
              });
          responsePromise.complete(queryResponses);
        })
    .onFailure(responsePromise::fail);
return responsePromise.future();


onComplete will wait for all the futures to complete (with success or failure) and only then the handler will be invoked.
In case of OnSuccess all the futures have to succeed, even if one future fails, the onFailure handler will be invoked instantly.
P.S: CompositeFuture's static reference to all() has been deprecated in newer vertx version. You might want to use CompositeFutureImpl.
For reference: https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/CompositeFuture.html
